# PHP in_array function doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays

I have some problems with in_array()
I want to create a unique number from  100-999 that is not stored in the array already, but the in_array function does not seem to work.
The example below is what my code is right now.

I have pushed 2 strings to the array in the top. In the function, I try to run it, but just get the value "sb100", and I should get "sb102" because 100 and 101 are already in the array.

```
$uniqueIDs[] = "sb100";
$uniqueIDs[] = "sb101";

function keyExists($ui){
    for($i=100;$i<=999;$i++){
        $R = "sb".$i;
        if(in_array($R, $ui)){
            return "";
        }else{
            return $R; 
            break;
        }
    }
}    

keyExists($uniqueIDs);
```

Comment: Can  you not do using `array_unique` ?

Comment: It would not be best use only `if(!in_array($R, $ui)) { return $R; }` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that as when it finds an element that already exists, it does `return "";`.  Instead you just continue if it's in the array and return if it isn't the array...

```
function keyExists($ui){
    for($i=100;$i<=999;$i++){
        $R = "sb".$i;
        if(!in_array($R, $ui)){
            return $R;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I have changed that now, but it still returns sb100

Comment: Nevermind, I just needed to change a thing that is unseen in the example, it works now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$uniqueIDs[] = "sb100";
$uniqueIDs[] = "sb101";

function keyExists($ui){
   for($i=100;$i<=999;$i++){
        $R = "sb".$i;
        if(!in_array($R, $ui)){
           return $R; 
       }
   }
```

}

```
echo keyExists($uniqueIDs);
```

You shouldn't return if match...